# How to debug GroovyScripts running directly in eclipse

Tags: groovy, groovy-eclipse

I'm trying debug a simple GroovyScript directly in eclipse but my breakpoints are never triggered. I'm using the Codehaus Groovy-Eclipse plugin only, do I need to configure beyond the defaults or use another plugin to be able to debug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually not being able to debug within a closure.  The SpringSource Groovy plugin makes this possible.